# uploading list items one by one to parse Server

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, parse-platform

```
Arraylist<String> users = new Arraylist<>();
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.FriendsView);
listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
arrayAdapter = new
ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,users);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long 
l) {
    CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) view;
    if(checkedTextView.isChecked()){

        Log.i("Info","Row is Checked!");
       ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("viewers").add(users.get(i));
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();

    }
    else{
        Log.i("Info","Row is not Checked!!");
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("viewers").remove(users.get(i));
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
    }
}
});
```

This is my code
I have to upload the string values one by one according to the value of `i` which is the index
but its uploading the value of string for the first time only
I have also used the `saveInBackground()` function with callback and its returning the callback message but not uploading the string value to the parse server.
'viewers' is a key in the User class of Parse of type List.

Comment: Share your complete code and error log?

Comment: There's no error.
It is showing the Log message 'Row is Checked'
But the data is not uploaded after first click to the parse server.